# Signing API requests with Coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion

I'm trying to work with the Kelkoo API (http://developer.kelkoo.com/samples/) as part of a project, and I've hit a brick wall when it comes to signing my requests.

As is usual for Coldfusion (sadly!) there are no code samples, and despite studying the other samples given, I really have no clue how to construct this (i.e they don't actually appear to say what they want anywhere!).

Maybe I'm missing something, but any pointers in the right direction would be appreciated!

Comment: OK, there are samples in other languages, they look pretty simple. Have you tried to port any of them to CFML? Any problems you had? For now you are asking people to do your job, sorry.

Comment: Yeah, I'd say start with the PHP version (or whichever one you're most comfortable with) and rewrite it in CFML.  Alternatively you could be able to use the Java one directly, given that ColdFusion is powered by Java in the background

Comment: Sorry, I realise that came across as asking people to do my job.  Coldfusion is the only language I use, and whilst I can usually decipher PHP to a degree, I'm lost with their example.  I did consider using the Java example, but again that's new to me (though I am currently googling ways of doing so!).

Comment: If you use cfscript at all, the java example would be the most similar. In fact the bulk of that function is just string concatenation. Only difference is java uses "+" instead of "&". The rest would be a few createObject("java") calls. You do not need any extra jars. It is all built into CF already. CF. Give it a shot and post back with a specific problem if you get stuck. http://developer.kelkoo.com/samples/signing-url-java/

Comment: Thanks Leigh - sounds simple enough so I'll give that a shot

Answer (score 1):

Use Java's as your sample: http://developer.kelkoo.com/samples/signing-url-java/

1. var your variables
2. System.currentTimeMillis() => `getTickCount()`
3. `+` string concat => `&` string concat
4. line 41: `tokken = hash(URLtmp & key, "md5", "ISO-8859-1")`
5. `hash()` returns hex, so you need `toBase64(BinaryDecode(tokken, "hex"))`
6. line 42: `replaceList(tokken, "+,/,=", ".,_,-")`

Comment: No, `hash("md5") returns hex.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <cfargument name="urlDomain" type="string" required="false" default="http://fr.shoppingapis.kelkoo.com" hint="kelkoo API domain"/>

    <!---
     Signature Kelkoo URL

        @param urlPath string (required) kelkoo path resources (ex: /V3/productSearch?query=table)
        @param secretKey string (required) kelkoo Secret Key 
        @param trackingId string (required) kelkoo tracking Id

        @param urlDomain    string (optional) kelkoo API domain default (http://fr.shoppingapis.kelkoo.com)

        @author Mauro Cardini (mcardini@decofinder.com) 
        @version 0, December, 2019 
    --->


    <cfset var theTimeStamp=int(getTickCount()/1000)>

    <cfset var URLtmp=arguments.urlPath & "&aid="& arguments.trackingId & "&timestamp=" & theTimeStamp>

     <cfset var tokken=hash(URLtmp & arguments.secretKey, "md5", "UTF-8")>

     <cfset tokken=toBase64(BinaryDecode(tokken, "hex"))>
     <cfset var thetokken=replaceList(tokken, "+,/,=", ".,_,-")>
     <cfset URLreturn = arguments.urlDomain & URLtmp & "&hash=" & theTokken>


<cfreturn URLreturn>
```